# How to return an operator from a function?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

How can I return operators in python? I tried this but it didn't work obviously:

```
def plus():
    return +
```

Is it even possible to write code like this without using the plus operator?

```
print(3plus()4)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: function without arguments just return the operator

Comment: The function can return the operator function, so you can do `plus()(3, 4)`, but `3plus()4` isn't valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
import operator
print(operator.add(3,4))
```

Comment: i want the function to return only the operator is that possible? without arguments